# How do I return an array from a reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an array of items. When the items update I dispatch an `UPDATED_LIST` action and pass along the item with its updated data.

For example:

```
const initialState = {
    items: []
}

const reducer = items(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATED_ITEMS':
            return { ...state, ...action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I dispatch like so:

```
store.dispatch({
    type: 'UPDATED_ITEMS',
    payload: [ { name: "bob"}, { name: "harry" } ]
})
```

And `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ items: state.items })
```

My problem is when I try to access `items` from within a component it's an object instead of an array. I have to do the following to get access to the array:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
    items: Object.keys(state.offers).map((k) => state.items[k])
})
```

Is it possible to get the items as an array without having to convert them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your reducer update it to where you set **items** with the action payload. You were previously using the spread operator on your action payload which converts all your array indexes into the state object as keys.

```
const reducer = items(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATED_ITEMS':
            return { ...state, items: [...action.payload] }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

If you don't want a nested state in your `mapStateToProps` you can do this where you make your initial state an array. Similar to the todo reducer shown here. https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list#reducerstodos.js

```
const initialState = [];

const reducer = items(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATED_ITEMS':
            return [ ...action.payload ];
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
  items: state.items
})
```

Comment: This produces another problem. When doing `combineReducers({ item: items, ... })` I still have to access with `state.items.items` (note items are nested 2 deep)  ... which is probably something I'm doing wrong. Other than that though this answer solves the problem.

Comment: You can make your initialState be an array. Similar to https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list#reducerstodos.js. Let me edit my example to show you what I mean

Comment: I figured out `combineReducers` will send a specific part of the state to each reducer. In my case the reducer's `state` would be the `items` portion of the state. No need to include `items: ...`. The following worked: `return [...state, ...action.payload]`. But for some reason it adds an empty array element. Getting close to solving.

Comment: Ah, I posted just before I spotted your edit. Ok, makes sense but why only return `...action.payload`, what about any items already in the current state?

Comment: If action.payload contains all the items you need for the redux state then you can just use spread only on `action.payload` but if you need the previous items (i.e adding onto the items then you should include `[...state, ...action.payload]`

Comment: Also I want to point out. If you're trying to replace items in the array while keeping your current state. You should probably do something similar to the `toggleTodo` in the link I sent you. Where it looks for specific items in the state and updates those.

Comment: Thanks. In this instance I only need to update the items list when new items are added. But, `[...state, ...action.payload]` returns `[[], { name: "harry"}]` for some reason. That empty array seems to be a result of the  spread operator and is being included in the state.

Comment: Did you make sure to update your initialState to []?

Comment: Also make sure your other actions aren't adding anything into your state. If you're getting [[], { name: "harray"}] that means something is in your state from another action or from initial state

Comment: Yeah, my initialState is just this: `export default (state = [], action)`

Comment: I thought that, but a `console.log` in the reducer is only getting called once. It's the only place it's being set. Also checked with Redux dev tools. Action is only called once.

Comment: Can you console.log your state right before `return [...state, ...action.payload]`? Does it log `[ [ ] ] `

Comment: `return [ ...state, ...action.payload ]` ... problem solved :D

Comment: Oh hah I was wondering if you had done `return [state, ...action.payload]` instead of `return [...state, ...action.payload]`